# C++ Threads : Trigger a loop from main thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++14

I have 4 sensors that I would like to poll asynchronously inside 4 different threads. I have a timer that will call a function at 30Hz and I would like this function to trigger the polling inside the threads.

I have tried using `std::async` to spawn 4 threads each time the timer calls but the overhead of creating the threads is too much. Here is what I did with `std::async`:

```cpp
for (auto& camera : camera_vector_) {
  camera_asyncs_.emplace_back(
      std::async(std::launch::async, [camera]() -> bool {
          return camera->poll();
      })
  );
}

for (auto& future : camera_asyncs_) {
  future.get();
}
```

---

Now I need my 4 threads to be spawned at the start of the program and wait for the clock to tell them to unlock and run the process function. something like this :

```cpp
for (auto& camera : camera_vector_)
{
  camera_threads_.emplace_back(std::thread([&camera]() {
    while (true)
    {
      wait_for_trigger();
      camera->poll();
      block_trigger();
    }
  }));
}

void Driver::poll_threads() {
  for (auto& thread : camera_threads_) {
    trigger_thread(thread);
  }
}
```

How would you do this ? my research led me to mutexes, and condition variables. For example [here](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/condition_variable/condition_variable/). But the examples I found were to start a bunch of threads and let them finish. not to trigger one loop in one thread at a time.

Also it seems that what I need here is not a thread pool, because each thread as a defined job that just need a trigger. Am I correct ?

It seems to me that using mutexes is the right thing to do. Should I store them in a second vector the same size as my thread vector ? I know I can lock a mutex inside the thread, but can I unlock the mutex from the main thread ? Do you have any tips for implementing this ?

I am using C++14.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: So when the timer triggers, it will spawn another four new threads?

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to perform the waiting inside of the threads, otherwise the mainthread is still bothered with signalling the threads?

Comment: @Yves Ideally not, I would like the threads to wait for the trigger.

Comment: It seems that what you need is indeed a thread pool. It would allow you to keep the 4 threads alive and to wake them up when you have to (when you give your thread pool a task to perform). But with mutex and condition variable, this is basically the same :)

Comment: @Fareanor What would be the simplest ? Any recommendation ?
Should I have one mutex then ?

Comment: @hetepeperfan Yes that's what I want to do.

Comment: Can you make sure that all of threads must be waiting to be triggered, instead of still working on the last job, or a thread can ignore some trigger if it's still busy?

Comment: It's fine if a thread is busy and misses one trigger.

Comment: @TheMackou The simplest is to use an already implemented thread pool. But if you want to do it by yourself, you should take a look at how [`std::condition_variable`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable) works. Once you understand what it does and how to use it, you will naturally find the solution of your issue (since this is a typical usage of `std::condition_variable` to keep a thread sleeping and wake it up when needed)

Comment: One thing struck me: "I have tried using std::async to spawn 4 threads each time the timer calls but the overhead of creating the threads is too much." It would really help if you created a [mcve] that illustrated exactly that. Also, it would help if you described observations, not just your interpretation that some overhead is too much.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my understanding about your need:

1. You just need four threads, no more no less;
2. The four threads are independent each other, meaning that they don't share data;
3. Each thread is triggered and do job every 33ms, in one 33ms, it can't do job more than once;
4. If a thread is still working on the last job while the trigger happening, the thread is allowed to ignore this trigger.

I will do the design as below:

```
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <atomic>

using namespace std;

std::atomic_flag lock0 = ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT;
std::atomic_flag lock1 = ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT;
std::atomic_flag lock2 = ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT;
std::atomic_flag lock3 = ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT;

void trigger() {
    while (true) {
        lock0.clear(); // set to false
        lock1.clear(); // set to false
        lock2.clear(); // set to false
        lock3.clear(); // set to false
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(33)); // 33 ms = 1000ms/30
        // from now on, all threads lost the chance to be triggered
        // they have to wait for the next time
        lock0.test_and_set(); // set to true
        lock1.test_and_set(); // set to true
        lock2.test_and_set(); // set to true
        lock3.test_and_set(); // set to true
    }
}

void f0()
{
    while (true) {
        while(!lock0.test_and_set()) {
            std::cout << "f0" << std::endl;
        }
    }
}

void f1()
{
    while (true) {
        while(!lock1.test_and_set()) {
            std::cout << "f1" << std::endl;
        }
    }
}

void f2()
{
    while (true) {
        while(!lock2.test_and_set()) {
            std::cout << "f2" << std::endl;
        }
    }
}

void f3()
{
    while (true) {
        while(!lock3.test_and_set()) {
            std::cout << "f3" << std::endl;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::thread> v; // use std::async if you want
    std::thread t(trigger);
    v.emplace_back(f0);
    v.emplace_back(f1);
    v.emplace_back(f2);
    v.emplace_back(f3);
    for (auto &ele : v) {
        ele.join();
    }
    t.join();

    return 0;
}
```

This code won't block, instead, it would keep running and do nothing untill the trigger comes.

Comment: Note that spinning on operations such as `test_and_set` is extremely inefficient since it involves cache contention. Better to spin on plain load/read until the lock is unlocked. See, e.g., [this article](https://rigtorp.se/spinlock/).

Comment: Moreover, in this setup, all atomic flags may end up in the same cache line, which would make things even worse. I would consider aligning them to cache line such as with `alignas(64)`.

Comment: @DanielLangr  But `std::atomic_flag` doesn't provide load or store operation... Is there any suggestion?

Comment: Sure, have you looked at the link I posted? They use `std::atomic<bool>` there.